# ERROR: free variable 'NAME' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Tags: python, mysql

I am making a hospital management system using PYTHON and MYSQL. Below is the code for booking an appointment.

```
elif list_==6:
        appt=int(input("""
1. Book appointment
2. Update appointment
3. Delete appointment
0. Exit
ENTER YOUR CHOICE:"""))
        if appt==1:
                def book_appt(): 
                    print('\n') 
                    PMR_NO= input('Patient Medical Record Number:')
                    cur.execute('select PMR_NO from patient')
                    reg=cur.fetchall()
                    for i in reg:
                        if (PMR_NO in i):
                            index=reg.index(i)
                            if (PMR_NO==reg[index][0]):
                                    DEPT= input('Department:')
                                    DOCTOR= input('Doctor\'s name:')
                                    ID_NO=input('Doctor\'s ID:')
                                    DATE=input('Appointment Date(YYYY-MM-DD):')
                                    TIME=input('Appointment Time(HH:MM:SEC):')
                                    rec3= 'insert into appointment(DEPT, DOCTOR, ID_NO, DATE,TIME) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,(select PMR_NO, NAME, PHONE_NO, EMAIL_ID, SPONSOR, INSURANCE_ID from patient))'
                                    column3= DEPT, DOCTOR, ID_NO, DATE, TIME, NAME, PHONE_NO, EMAIL_ID, SPONSOR, INSURANCE_ID, PMR_NO
                                    cur.execute(rec3, column3)
                                    print("""APPOINTMENT BOOKED SUCCESSFULLY""")
                                    print('\n')
                                    conn.commit()
                                    admin_det()
                            else:
                                 print('USER NOT FOUND IN THE DATABASE')
                                 print('PLEASE REGISTER AGAIN')
                                 admin_det()
                book_appt()
```

However, when I run this code I am getting an error that says:
NameError: free variable 'NAME' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

How to correct this error?
Thanks for your help
CHEERS!

Comment: I don't think you have enough "%s" terms, as there are 5 of them but 6 variables

Comment: I checked, there are only 5 variables and 5 '%s'

Comment: i think it is 6

Comment: PMR_NO 1, NAME 2, PHONE_NO 3, EMAIL_ID 4, SPONSOR, 5, INSURANCE_ID 6

Comment: I tried adding another '%s', but it still returns the same error. Could you please let me know what is the 6th variable?

Comment: i think that whatever function you called to set the variables is out of scope for your variables, try initialising them at the top of your script (they dont have to have values just tell python you want them to be globally scoped)

Comment: I am really sorry to ask this since I am new to coding. Can you please explain how do i initalize? Does intialize mean, i have to ask the user to input the data?

Comment: no don't worry it just means to write out the variable names before anything else - this should just tell python that these variables shouldn't be forgotten when the code block they were defined in ends (they go out of scope)        like `PMR_NO, NAME, PHONE_NO, EMAIL_ID, SPONSOR, INSURANCE_ID`

Comment: other than that rlly im not sure bc i dont have much experience w mysql

Comment: Alright thanks a lot for your input!! I'll try doing what you suggested

Comment: Do you really need to capture patient details other than PMR in the appointments table?, you can grab that later with a simple join if need be.

Comment: What i am planning is, when the doctor logins, they can choose the option of viewing all their appointments. So when they view it, they have to see all the details and hence I coded this way.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: You prompt for a bunch of things, but `NAME` isn’t one of them.  Evidently you eventually assign to that variable (outside `book_appt`), but you haven’t **yet**.